# App's custom domain name must match certificate CN

Tags: ssl, parse-platform, ssl-certificate

I'm having a hard time adding my SSL cert on Parse.

I get  this "App's custom domain name must match certificate CN" error.  I've been following this https://www.digicert.com/csr-creation-ssl-installation-parse-php-sdk.htm#install_ssl_certificate tutorial even though i'm using javascript for my backend not PHP.

I get a checkmark (no errors) when I add my Host name so there's nothing wrong with that it would seem. I've created a .pem file with the entire SSL cert trust chain, tried uploading it but I get the same error. And just for the heck of it I also uploaded my Primary Cert without attaching intermediary or root certs which didn't work either.

I've created the CSR similar to what was shown in the example. Are there any other online help like a pay per session with a Parse developer?  Because this is driving me crazy

In the Parse docs Https section it just says to upload your custom domain cert. I have my cert for my custom domain and I'm trying to upload it so why am I getting this error?

Comment: Got the exact same problem. Did you by any chance find a solution for this? thx